# Site refused to connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I have a site hosted on AWS EC2 instance. I stopped the instance and started it up again and noticed the IP address had changed. Due to complications with this happening posts I read online suggested using an elastic IP. I allocated one and associated it with my EC2 instance. I also made sure that my hosted zone is pointing to my elastic IP. Now when I try to go to my domain I get the error "[site] refused to connect". I am able to ssh into my instance via terminal using the elastic IP. I am lost on where to go next. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the domain resolve to it? You may need to clear your local cache. Try using https://www.whatsmydns.net/ or dig on the CLI to verify the change.

Comment: Yes, the public IP address for my site comes up on [whatsmydns.net - output](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.mattborgman.com). Also when I test my hosted zones on the AWS console I get `NOERROR`. Everything seems to point towards it should be working, but I still cannot access site via web browser.

Comment: Yea, https and http is closed, I would double check your security group for the ec2 instance. Also I would not have ssh open to the world. https://pastebin.com/SmzC1EKy

Comment: I just checked my security group that is attached to my EC2 instance and the http and https is open on port 80 and 443 respectively to all IP addresses. This is the same setup that was working fine before my IP address got changed. If that still sounds wrong please let me know , but from what I can tell my security group is set up correctly.

Comment: is it hard coded in the web server config and/or is the web server started.

Comment: The web server is started, at least the ec2 instance is running. Will have to check the web server configs not sure where those are located.

Comment: wow... so you are right @strongjz, apache was not running, so this whole time all I had to do was start my web server LOL. Thank you so much for the assistance. I will remember this for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @strongjz I have the answer to the question. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future. Once you stop an amazon EC2 instance, not only do you need to check your IP address as it will change but also make sure to ssh into your instance and run `sudo service httpd start` to make sure that your web server is running. This was the problem for me. Took me days to figure it out. Big thanks to @strongjz for helping me with this!